# How to convert the xml log into tabular output in Splunk

Tags: splunk

Am new to splunk and am trying to have the xml log data into splunk and create report.
I have xml data which is being fed to splunk server. below is the format of data am having

`<str name=size>3.32mb</str>`

I want to extract this details and have this transformed in tabular format. like below 
`Size | 3.32mb`

I read something about xmlkv but i think it works on xml data like `<size>3.32mb</size>`  but i am not sure how this will work for my  requirement.

Could anyone please help me in understand this and also guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your xml data is in a field called "xml", you can extract what you want with this:

```
xpath outfield=name field=xml "//str/@name" | spath input=xml output=sizeval path=str | fields name, sizeval
```

See the splunk help about xpath and spath - the examples are good enough to guide you.